# import xls cells into html

Tags: html, excel, import

I want to create an html template that can fetch the (sometimes long) texts of cells in an xls database into specific locations in the body. The html will then be saved to a unique document and will not be changed anymore.

I've been searching the web for days now and any help will be most appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Fetch what using what platform from where? I don't understand. Please make an example

Answer (score 3):

You need to use some dynamic web language like PHP (there're some pretty classes out there for the job) or ASP to fetch the records you need and print them in html accordingly..